# Tabs bar disappeared from android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

[image: Android Studio]

As shown in the picture, the tabs bar for XML and java files disappeared in my android studio.

Anyone can help me solve this problem, please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please go to Preferences >> Editor >> General >> Editor Tabs >> select Placement: Top for example

Comment: glad to help Ali, please Accept my answer